# Split JSON file based on row count and not data size azure data factory

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

My problem is, I am trying to use Azure Data Factory (ADF) to push data to a web service to write to a target system. However, ADF has a limitation with the web service step of 1 minute. I need to over come this problem, and I am trying to split the json file into multiple files.

Process:

1. Email is received with a CSV file
2. CSV file is put into Blob storage
3. CSV file is converted to JSON
4. Write to target system using API

Step 4 times out after 1 minute. So I am looking to work around this problem, and my first inclination was split the chunk of json data up and pass each chunk of data to the API via a loop in ADF.

Challenge I face is how to break up the json file based on entries and not size.

I have tried using metadata in ADF to just get the count but I haven't been successful at this.

Basic Flow:
[image]
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[Get Metadata activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity#supported-connectors) can't get columnCount from JSON

> structure and columnCount are not supported when getting metadata from
> Binary, JSON, or XML files.

You can create an Azure Function and pass your JSON data to it. Then you can split JSON data to several chunk in Azure Function. Finally loop these chunk by For Each or Until activity and execute step4 in it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up designing a work around based on this site:
https://mssqldude.wordpress.com/2019/03/23/partition-large-files-with-adf-using-mapping-data-flows/?unapproved=15536&moderation-hash=29d80505967897ac8f8a8699060012f5#comment-15536

Using a dataflow, I just have a source and a sink, and in the sink I optimized for a partition type of round robin. Each file generated in the partition is then passed to a for each where the API then reads one at a time.

I am still figuring out more in terms of making even more efficient. One of my challenges is that the number of records in the JSON is not static and can vary greatly between runs, which is why I was wanting to find how to split based on records.

[image: New Flow]